# How to find a string in a folder and return the value using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to match a string inside a file. If it matched, it will return the path of the file, if it is not matched it will return false.
Using this code I can match and find the path if the string match, but if the string doesn't match it returns this error:

> Get-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

```
$Path = "D:\190\Pro"
$SS = "1q1q"
$Paths = (Get-Item (Get-ChildItem "$Path\*\LST" | Select-String -Pattern "$SS").Path).Directory.FullName
if ($Paths) {
    Write-Host "Found Path"
    #Do next process
} else {
    Write-Host "Not Found Path"
    #Do next process
}
```

Comment: what is in the target file?

Comment: The target file is `LST`

Comment: i repeat --- what is IN THE TARGET FILE, not what _IS THE TARGET FILE_. [*grin*]

Comment: it is string inside the target file

Comment: your code says that `LST` is a path. ... i am wanting to know WHAT IS THE TEXT IN THE FILE?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Why does that matter? According to the question the code works when it finds a match. It only fails when no match is found. Hence the issue is not with the content of the files but the processing of the (empty) results.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - perhaps i am too focused on the glitch ... but i cannot understand what the OP is trying to actually do ... and the stopping point in my understanding is the target file that is being translated into a path. without that info ... who knows what the actual trigger for the error is?

Answer (score 1):

If `Get-ChildItem | Select-String` doesn't produce a match you have an empty result in the nested expression. Passing that empty result to `Get-Item` will essentially run `Get-Item $null`, which throws the error you observed, because the `-Path` parameter of that cmdlet doesn't accept `$null` as an argument.

Replace the needlessly convoluted

```
$Paths = (Get-Item (Get-ChildItem "$Path\*\LST" | Select-String -Pattern "$SS").Path).Directory.FullName
```

with

```
$Paths = Get-ChildItem "$Path\*\LST" |
         Where-Object { Select-String -Path $_.FullName -Pattern "$SS" } |
         Select-Object -Expand DirectoryName
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: But how do I get the path if it is match?